# what takes more VM?

Tags: android, static, bitmap, arrays, virtual-machine

I have some static bitmaps in my app so they can be used between different classes and they overload the VM, if i make these same bitmaps into byte[]'s will that fix the problem?

thank you for your time

Comment: Do you mean you have stored image data in your code? Consider storing them as resources which would be the best Android practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt this will help, since `Bitmap` objects also use `byte[]` for storing the actual data. Instead of that, I'd recommend you to make better use of your `Bitmaps`: load them only when you need them and recycle as soon as they become unnecessary. [Here's](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) a nice topic from the Android Training that discusses efficient handling of large `Bitmaps`. Hope this helps.

Comment: hey thanks man, problem solved looking at your link, i know what i have to do now

Comment: the only bitmap that overloads the budget is if i take from camera gallery and i know that that one is high resolution so i have to use Options

Comment: @JRowan, Glad you've found the solution.